# oci8-2.2.0 does not connect to the database but doesn't return an error either

Tags: php, docker, oci8

I'm trying to install oci8-2.2.0 on an ubuntu 18 docker with php 7.2
I'm using the following commands (php-pear and libc6 installed before those):

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip libaio1 libsnl-dev && \
    cd /tmp && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/214000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    mkdir -p /opt/oracle && \
    cp instantclient-* /opt/oracle/ && \
    cd /opt/oracle/ && \
    unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-21.4.0.0.0dbru.zip && \
    ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/libclntsh.so.21.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
    ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
    ln -s /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/libnnz21.so /usr/lib/libnnz21.so && \
    ln -s  /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4/libclntshcore.so /usr/lib/libclntshcore.so.21.1 && \
    echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf

RUN echo "instantclient,/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4" | pecl install oci8-2.2.0 && \
    echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini && \
    echo "extension=oci8.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

PHP Seems to recognize the module and load it, but when I call @oci_new_connect I don't get a connection, but I don't get an error either.

Using sqlplus from the same server connects just fine, so its not that. Another installation with the adminer 4.8.1 docker (alpine & php 7.4) works fine.

I'm completely stumped. Does anyone have an idea where to look next?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, needed to add

```
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_4
```